# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Passenger Standalone - Rails not setting asset cache headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-caching

I have a rails application running on AWS EB with passenger standalone. However the asset served doesn't seem to set cache headers. What is the preferred way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the nginx configuration template from aws.
For passenger running on:
64bit Amazon Linux 2015.09 v2.0.6 running Ruby 2.2 (Passenger Standalone)

It configures rails assets with 32bit digest at the end while it's 64bit in rails 4.2

Thanks Daniel for the information.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phusion-passenger/Tqmx09coB48